# How to programically shrink a button and rearrange the rest of the layout accordingly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a layout across the bottom of my screen with 4 buttons and a Space in the center. The space is there for a FAB to be displayed above it, but when the layout is hidden, I want to shrink the space in the center to 0dp so that the 4 buttons span evenly across the screen.

I tried using a ViewPropertyAnimator to scale the width to 0, but it does not work.

How can I shrink and expand the space in the center of the 4 buttons programatically (and ideally, animated), such that the 4 buttons will resize and move according to the size of the space?

The layout code I'm using is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it's visibility to GONE

```
<Space
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

and the simpler animation method it's to add this line to the root tag of the Layout XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
```

Comment: I never expected the solution to be this elegant. It works perfectly, thanks!